# what is use of tag <databaseSettings> in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to know what is the use of tag  in web.config file and what role it plays.
Can someone refer me to documentation resource or explain to me the use of this tag and it's properties.

Comment: Can you post a (redacted) example?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear in the standard layout of a web.config file as far as I can see.

- [Details on Configuration Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228147(v=vs.100).aspx) (MSDN)

The [standard way of handling db connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx) in a web.config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="NorthwindConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

This could be a [custom section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) in your config, in which case it would be defined as:

```
<configuration>
<!-- Configuration section-handler declaration area. -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="databasesettings">
```